# Why do I need "use rand::Rng" to call gen() on rand::thread_rng()?

Tags: rust, module, traits

When I'm using Rust's rand crate, if I want to produce a rand number, I would write:

```
use rand::{self, Rng};
let rand = rand::thread_rng().gen::<usize>();
```

If I don't `use rand::Rng`, an error occurs:

> no method named `gen` found for struct `rand::prelude::ThreadRng` in the current scope

That's quite different from what I'm used to. Usually I treat mods like:

```js
import rand from "path";
rand.generate();
```

Once I import the mod I don't need to import something else, and I can use every method it exports.

Why must I `use rand::Rng` to enable the `gen` method on `rand::thread_rng()`?

Comment: As a side note, by including rand in your cargo.toml it the compiler will automatically bring the symbol `rand` in scope everywhere, so there is no need to import it. Also, both `rand::thread_rng` and `rand::Rng` are included in rand's prelude, so `use rand::prelude::*;` is the recommended way to bring the symbols in scope.

Answer (score 7):

> That's quite different from what I used to know.

It feels different because it *is* indeed different. You are probably used to dynamic dispatch via some kind of virtual method table (as in e.g. C++), or, in case of JS, to dynamic dispatch by looking up either the own properties of the receiver object, or its ancestors via the `__proto__`-chain. In any case, the object on which you are invoking a method carries around some data that tells it how to get the method that you're invoking. Given the signature of the invoked method, the receiver object itself knows how to get the method with that signature.

That's not the only way, though. For example,

- modules / functors in OCaml or SML
- Typeclasses in Haskell
- `implicit`s / `given`s in Scala
- traits in Rust

work on a rather different principle: the methods are not tied to the receiver, but to the module / typeclass / given / trait instances. In each case, those are entities that are separate from the receiver of the method call. It opens some new possibilities, e.g. it allows you to do some ad-hoc polymorphism (i.e. to define instances of traits after the fact, for types that are not necessarily under your control). At the same time, the compiler typically requires a bit more information from you in order to be able to select the correct instances: it behaves somewhat like a little type-directed search engine, or even a little "theorem prover", and for this to work, you have to tell the compiler where to look for the suitable building blocks for those synthetically generated instances.

If you've never worked before with any language that has a compiler with a subsystem that is "searching for instances" based on type information, this should indeed feel quite foreign. The error messages and the solution approaches do indeed feel rather different, because instead of comparing your implementation against an interface and looking for conflicts, you have to guide this instance-searching mechanism by providing more hints (e.g. by importing more traits etc.).

In your particular case, [`rand::thread_rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/fn.thread_rng.html) returns a *struct* [`ThreadRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html). On its own, the struct knows nothing about the `gen` method, because this method is not tied directly to the struct. Instead, it's defined in the [`Rng` *trait*](https://docs.rs/rand/0.5.0/rand/trait.Rng.html). But at the same time, it *could* be defined in some entirely unrelated trait, and have some completely different meaning. In order to disambiguate the intended meaning, you therefore have to explicitly specify that you want to work with the `Rng` trait. This is why you have to mention it in the `use`-clause.

Comment: Really apprecaiting your answer. Just like you said, the error message didn't help me    find the solution at first. And I'm a newbie to this kind of language, sometimes I'm restricted by the past way of thinking.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know the specific library you're using, but I can guess at the problem. I would guess that `Rng` is a trait which defines `gen`. Traits can be thought of as somewhat like Java's interfaces: they enable ad-hoc polymorphism by allowing you to define different behaviors for the same function on different datatypes.

However, Rust's traits fix one major problem (well, they fix several major problems, but one that's relevant here) with Java's interfaces. In Java, if you define an interface, then anyone writing a class can implement the interface, but you can't implement it for other people. In particular, the built-in types `String` and `int` and the like can *never* implement any new interfaces downstream. In Rust, either the trait writer *or* the struct/enum writer can implement the trait.

But this poses another issue. Now, if I have a value `foo` of type `Foo` and I write `foo.bar()`, then `bar` might not be a method defined *on* `Foo`; it might be something some `trait` writer implemented in some other file. We can't go search every Rust file on your computer for possible matching traits, so Rust makes the logical decision to restrict this search to traits that are in scope. If you want to call `foo.bar()` and `bar` is a method on `trait Bar`, then `trait Bar` has to be in scope when you call it. Otherwise, Rust won't see it.

So, in your case, `thread_rng()` returns a `rand::prelude::ThreadRng`. The method `gen` is *not* defined on `rand::prelude::ThreadRng`. Instead, it's defined on a trait called `rand::Rng` which is *implemented by `ThreadRng`. That trait has to be in-scope to use the method.

Comment: thanks! seems I have to read the trait chapter again.